# push-to-listen-into-the-past with pyaudio

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

Essentially, what I want to achieve is upon triggering, the previous two seconds and further audio should be recorded, until silence.

For this, of course, the microphone has to listen all the time and record to a circular buffer. Upon triggering, current audio shall be recorded until there is a long enough span of silence. In the end, both streams should be combined to a single audio file/stream.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to wrap my head around how to achieve this with pyaudio.

I would be great if you had some advice for me.